# Is there a Solr-Camel component?

Tags: solr, apache-camel

I've been looking for this for a while and haven't found anything yet. Is there any reason to that ? I would like to proxy a solr server with the camel integration framework and I understand it must be quite straight forward without it, but less elegant :).

If someone has worked on this, I would love some feedback.

Nicolas.

Comment: Hi Nicolas,

Any progress on you component? I would be interested on working on that.

@Claus: Hi Claus, I have just read Camel in Action... wow!! Congrats! I already had experience with Camel, and CIA brought me the knowledge I needed to understand the whole picture and like Camel even more. Would you like to get the book reviewed somewhere in special (Amazon, Manning,...)?

Could you suggest any of the available Camel components as basis for the Solr component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yep, there is a new [camel-solr](http://camel.apache.org/solr.html) component

Answer (score 1):

There is an Apache Lucene component
http://camel.apache.org/lucene

But I dont think anyone has done any Apache Solr component. However in the end its all Java code, so you should be able to leverage them together.

Also check out github as people spin off projects there creating all kind of Camel related components.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't find anything on github. I guess I will also end up spinning off my project ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have build a Camel Solr endpoint as part of a search project. Solr and Camel fits smoothly and I have had no problems. Its available at [here](http://www.villemos.com/?q=ispace/component/solr). Its still in the early days, i.e. I'm writing the documentation and testing as we speak.

It would be great if you could try it out and provide feedback, both to its usage as well as to the documentation.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is a camel-solr component proposal https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-4539